# Create a trigger that won't let updating the primary key columns

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, composite-primary-key

I have a table that has a composite primary key made from 3 columns, let's say A, B, C. I want to create a trigger that on `UPDATE` will check that these three columns won't be changed. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableTrigger
ON Table
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted))
    BEGIN
    -- Update Operation
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted WHERE A IS NOT NULL OR B IS NOT NULL OR C IS NOT NULL) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Error, you cannot change Primary Key columns', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END
END
```

I was expecting that if I update some values in a table, in `inserted` the values for the columns I don't update to be NULL, but it's not like that. I read somewhere that I need to look both in `inserted` and `deleted` to see if these values changed. So my question is this, can I check this without using a cursor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableTrigger
ON Table
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
IF UPDATE(A) OR UPDATE(B) OR UPDATE(C) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Error, you cannot change Primary Key columns', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END
END
```

Or deny update permissions on those columns.

Both approaches would deny any attempt to update the PK columns irrespective of whether or not the values actually change. SQL Server does not have row level triggers and unless there is an `IDENTITY` column in the table (guaranteed immutable) there is no reliable way to tell in a trigger if the PK was actually updated.

For example the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables in an `UPDATE` trigger on the table below would be identical for both the `UPDATE` statements.

```
CREATE TABLE T(C INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1),(-1)

/*Both values swapped*/
UPDATE T SET C = -C

/*Both values left the same*/
UPDATE T SET C = C
```